# Metabase-BQ Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: google-bigquery, metabase

While connecting Metabase with BigQuery, getting following error, Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

```
403 Forbidden POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/aldun-console/queries { "code" : 403, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.", "reason" : "accessDenied" } ], "message" : "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.", "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED" }
```

I was trying to connect metabase with bigquery, and as described created a service account, and added details while adding database.

When running the view, getting above error.

Comment: Check if you are connect to your GCP account via gcluod